# Talend connectors available or not

Tags: talend

I want to connect with following tools.So Are the following connectors available in Talend?.Please suggest me.
    1)BuiltWith
    2)Datanyze
    3)New Relic 
    4)Zend Desk

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the following link for you to peruse that will allow you to see what components are available for each Talend product.

https://www.talendforge.org/components/

For example, I looked at Talend Open Studio for Data Integration (6.2.0) and did not find any components for BuiltWith, Datanyze, New Relic or Zend Desk.

HTH